Check if object exists in specific collection (Geometry Nodes)
Similar to this Python Boolean expression, I am wondering if there's a way to determine if a specific object exists within a Collection through Geometry Nodes.
For example, this GN Modifier could be freely added to any object in the scene. The Geometry Input is compared to the Instances in a Collection Info node (ideally without realising the Collection), and returns True if the mesh is found in the Collection.
This would be really useful for making Collections that have specific GN functionality (ie, move a Suzanne from the "1x Scale" collection to the "2x Scale" collection).
If there's any other approaches/more performant methods to do something like this, I'm open to exploring them. Thanks for the help :)

I think the newly added naming of geometry serves this exact purpose. It would mean no need to compare anything, just name your objects are identify them with it. I haven't play with names yet so it's more of a guess.

This could be one to consider (maybe setting the name by a driver expression from the Python thread linked), but I'm looking for a more dynamic approach than manually renaming each element. This way an object could be moved between collections and inherit GN settings for that specific collection.

I see, you could still give dynamic names in GN but it would mean all objects need to have a GN that sets geometry names.

You can take advantage of a Blender defense mechanism that does exactly that:

If the collection contains the object itself, it shows you a warning and returns nothing.
Unfortunately this method will fail if you pass an empty collection

Empty collection or no collection. Maybe at some point we will be able to read warnings inside geonodes.

That's a hilariously good solution  Works exactly as needed, thanks for the help!
